# A list of string into a nested list of string

Tags: python, string, list, nested

so I need to turn a list of str into a list of list of str.

EX:

```
thing = [' a b c', 'e f g']
```

into:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g']]
```

My code keeps returning a mistake:

```
coolthing = []   
abc = []
for line in thing:
    abc = coolthing.append(line.split())
return abc
```

Answer (score 3):

`list.append` operates in-place and always returns `None`.  So, `abc` will be `None` when you return it.

To do what you want, you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
return [x.split() for x in thing]
```

Demo:

```
>>> thing = [' a b c', 'e f g']
>>> [x.split() for x in thing]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g']]
```

Comment: `return map(str.split,thing)` for a functional apporach

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - +1.  I actually thought about doing that initially, but then you'd have to do `return list(map(str.split,thing))` if the OP was using Python 3.x.  Nice thing about the list comp. is it works the same in both versions.

Comment: Your way is probably better for the OP, just thought I would throw it in there.

Comment: Based on [my rudimentary testing](http://pastebin.com/Me2k407q) with timeit, the functional approach is nominally faster.

Comment: @pzp1997 - True.  In Python 2.x, the `map` approach will be faster because most of the work (i.e. the looping) is being done in C and not Python.  Note however that in Python 3.x, the list comp. outperforms `list(map(str.split,thing))`.  Mainly though, I used the list comp. for portability.  It also seems slightly more readable to me.